# Left Join on Linq query when also using the Where clause on joint table

Tags: c#, linq

I can see this question has been asked a few times but I am puzzled as to how to implement for myself.

I am using SQL Lite and i am trying to join 2 tables but sometimes the 'linked' row in the 2nd table does not exist.

This is my code:

```
return from address in DB.Connector.Table<InformedWorkerModel.Tables.Address>()
       join addressHistory in DB.Connector.Table<InformedWorkerModel.Tables.AddressHistory>() 
       on address.AddressRef equals addressHistory.AddressRef 
       where addressHistory.CustomerRef == customerRef 
       select new InformedWorkerModel.Tables.Address
       {
           Address1 = address.Address1,
           Address2 = address.Address2,
           Address3 = address.Address3,
           Town = address.Town,
           County = address.County,
           Country = address.Country,
           PostCode = address.PostCode,
           AddressRef = address.AddressRef,
           AddressId = address.AddressId
       };
```

On Googling i can see a solution if I do not use a 'where' clause.. but i am..

Comment: What do you want? To return data even if there's no rows in the `addressHistory` table? In that case you need the equivalent of a "left join".

Comment: `from address in DB.Connector.Table<InformedWorkerModel.Tables.Address>()
from addressHistory in DB.Connector.Table<InformedWorkerModel.Tables.AddressHistory>().Where(ah => ah.CustomerRef == customerRef).DefaultIfEmpty()
select new ...`

Comment: @ChrisF Hi chris thanks for your question. Yes, i am looking for a Left join but how do i perform it with the where clause being there?

Comment: @Dennis_E thanks will look and if same will delete my question

Comment: @Dennis_E slightly different as my question was with the inclusion of the where clause but thanks for flagging :)

Comment: @GiladGreen thanks will look at . just trying to see if the solution proposed works at the moment. I know flagged as duplicate but the other answers do not include the where clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the use of [`DefaultIfEmpty()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360179(v=vs.110).aspx) part which is what turns it into a left join *(Check out the documentation - it shows very clear how to perform all the different joins)*:

```
   from address in DB.Connector.Table<InformedWorkerModel.Tables.Address>()
   join addressHistory in (from x in DB.Connector.Table<InformedWorkerModel.Tables.AddressHistory>() 
                           where x.CustomerRef == customerRef
                           select x) 
   on address.AddressRef equals addressHistory.AddressRef into j
   from addressHistory in j.DefaultIfEmpty()
   select new InformedWorkerModel.Tables.Address
   {
       Address1 = address.Address1,
       Address2 = address.Address2,
       Address3 = address.Address3,
       Town = address.Town,
       County = address.County,
       Country = address.Country,
       PostCode = address.PostCode,
       AddressRef = address.AddressRef,
       AddressId = address.AddressId
   };
```

Also see that I moved the `addressHistory.CustomerRef == customerRef` to a nested select. If you do not do so then you will only get rows which have a value for it - which **effectively turns this into a "normal" `inner join`**.
Another way is like before but:

```
where addressHistory == null || addressHistory.CustomerRef == customerRef
```

So it will look like:

```
   from address in DB.Connector.Table<InformedWorkerModel.Tables.Address>()
   join addressHistory in DB.Connector.Table<InformedWorkerModel.Tables.AddressHistory>() 
   on address.AddressRef equals addressHistory.AddressRef into j
   from addressHistory in j.DefaultIfEmpty()
   where addressHistory == null || addressHistory.CustomerRef == customerRef
   select new InformedWorkerModel.Tables.Address
   {
       Address1 = address.Address1,
       Address2 = address.Address2,
       Address3 = address.Address3,
       Town = address.Town,
       County = address.County,
       Country = address.Country,
       PostCode = address.PostCode,
       AddressRef = address.AddressRef,
       AddressId = address.AddressId
   };
```

Comment: thanks i was trying to work out where to put the DefaultIfEmpty. New to this stuff. thanks again :)

Comment: @AndrewSimpson - Your are welcome :) Saw you edited title - good :) Added an extra edit :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return data even when there's no rows in the `addressHistory` table for this address then you need to do the equivalent of a SQL "left join":

```
join addressHistory in DB.Connector.Table<InformedWorkerModel.Tables.AddressHistory>()
     on address.AddressRef equals addressHistory.AddressRef
     into joinedAddressHistories
     from joinedHistory in joinedAddressHistories.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

However, you'll also need to modify your `where` clause as that will now fail if you try:

```
where joinedHistory.CustomerRef = customerRef
```

as joinedHistory will be null. Without knowing exactly what you want here I can't suggest a solution.

Comment: thanks again. Let me look at these 2 answers and the comment from Michael